# Using df.isin() function over a column of tuples | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, plotly, coordinates

I have a dataframe consisting of Wikipedia articles with geocoordinates and some statistics. The column 'Availability' contains a tuple of the languages that article is available in (out of a selection).

What I'm trying to do is plot a bubble map with plotly, and the legend being the availability in those languages. For example, out of `['ca','es']` you would have `[],['ca'],['es'],['ca','es']` meaning not available, only in catalan, only in spanish or available in both respectively.

The problem is that when trying to use those combinations to create a dataframe with only the matching rows using Dataframe.isin(), it always returns an empty df.
The columns of the dataframe are:
`Columns: [French Title, Qitem, Pageviews, page_title_1, page_title_2, Availability, Lat, Lon, Text]`

Here is my code:

```
    fig = go.Figure()
    scale = 500
    for comb in combinations:

        df_sub = df[df['Availability'].isin(tuple(comb))] #The problem is here. This returns an empty DF
        
        if(len(df_sub.index)) == 0: continue #There are no occurrencies with that comb
        fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
            lat=df_sub['Lat'],
            lon=df_sub['Lon'],
            text=df_sub['Text'],
            marker = dict(
                size = df[order_by],
                sizeref=2. * max(df[order_by]) / (scale ** 2),
                line_color='rgb(40,40,40)',
                line_width=0.5,
                sizemode='area'
            ), name = comb #Here is the underlying restriction. I need to separate the traces according to their availability.
        ))
```

PS: I guess it has something to do with pandas not working very good with using lists or tuples as a column value, but didn't figure out how to achieve what I want. Any of you has any idea? Thank you in advance. **Comb appears as a string or a tuple of strings: `('es','ca')` , but the values in df['Availability] when I print them appear like `(es,ca)`**

Sample dataframe (sorry for the style I'm new to Stack overflow)**

```
    French Title      Qitem  Pageviews  \
0  Liban                       Q822       53903       
1  France                      Q142       25728       
2  BiÃ©lorussie                 Q184       21688       
3  ÃŽle Maurice                 Q2656389   20478       
4  Affaire Dupont de LigonnÃ¨s  Q16010109  16075       

                                        page_title_1  page_title_2  \
0  LÃ­bano                                             LÃ­ban          
1  Francia                                            FranÃ§a         
2  Bielorrusia                                        BielorÃºssia    
3  Isla de Mauricio                                   Illa Maurici   
4  Asesinatos y desapariciones de Dupont de LigonnÃ¨s                 

  Availability              Lat              Lon  \
0  (es, ca)     33.90000000      35.53330000       
1  (es, ca)     48.86700000      2.32650000        
2  (es, ca)     53.528333333333  28.046666666667   
3  (es, ca)     -20.30084200     57.58209200       
4  (es,)        47.23613230      -1.56848610       

                                                                    Text  
0  Liban<br>(33.90000000, 35.53330000)<br>Q822                            
1  France<br>(48.86700000, 2.32650000)<br>Q142                            
2  BiÃ©lorussie<br>(53.528333333333, 28.046666666667)<br>Q184              
3  ÃŽle Maurice<br>(-20.30084200, 57.58209200)<br>Q2656389                 
4  Affaire Dupont de LigonnÃ¨s<br>(47.23613230, -1.56848610)<br>Q16010109
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your DataFrame? That would help other developers reproduce your problem or get a better idea about why your are getting certain errors

Comment: @DerekO True, I forgot. I made an edit with the df.head() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.apply()` to achieve your goal:

```
df['Availability'].apply(lambda x: 'ca' in x)
```

That will return `True` if `'ca'` is in the tuple. It can easily be modified to return some label, eg. `Catalan`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried df_sub = df[df['Availability'].apply(lambda x: tuple(comb) in x)] but that didn't work out. What I need to know is if the value in the column is exactly like my tuple, not if a language is in the tuple. That way I can separate between articles that exist in both languages, only in es, only in ca or don't exist in those languages.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I turned the tuple into a list because due to not using `df.isin()` it doesn't raise the `Unhashable Type Error`, and was able to separate the traces via combinations using `df.apply()` (thanks to mkos for the idea):

```
 for comb in combinations:

    if len(comb) ==0:
        name ='Not available'
        df_sub = df[df['Availability'].apply(lambda x:  len(x)==0)]
    else:
        df_sub = df[df['Availability'].apply(lambda x: set(comb) == set(x))]
        name = ','.join(comb)
    if(len(df_sub.index)) == 0: continue
   

    fig.add_trace(go.Scattergeo(
        lat=df_sub['Lat'],
        lon=df_sub['Lon'],
        text=df_sub['Text'],
        marker = dict(
            size = df[order_by],
            sizeref=2. * max(df[order_by]) / (scale ** 2),
            line_color='rgb(40,40,40)',
            line_width=0.5,
            sizemode='area'
        ), name =name
    ))
```

You can see the result [here](https://wdo-dev.wmcloud.org/map_of_gaps/).